# Android Studio: Email fill on gmail?

Tags: android, email, android-studio

I've integrated code to send an email from my app.i have search on that and found the solution which i have already integrated but it didn't work for me.

Basically, The code include the **text** and the **subject** but does not add the **email address** (on which we have to send email) in gmail.

Can any one help me?

```
 protected void sendEmail (String strtwi){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "projectmyangel@hotmail.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Spread More Cheer!");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strtwi);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "projectmyangel@hotmail.com");
```

with

```
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myEmail@gmail.com"});
```

if above didn't solve your issue try below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"myEmail@gmail.com"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Contact Me..."));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android API does not supply the assignment of the email address (on which to send mail).

The intent is just a message that sent to the application you select in `Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email")` and fill in the necessary columns refer to the information you have given.

Since the email address that the mail sent from differs from one user to another, it is better to choose them in the email application the user select rather than in your application.